# WordPress Enforce https through .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've been doing some 301 redirects as Google has cached/save old links. So I set up my 301 redirects:

```
Redirect 301 /old/url/ /index.php/old/url
```

however I noticed the url weren't `https://` they were `www.example.com/index.php/old/url`

I did some searching online for enforce `https` via `.htaccess` but everything I try causes whole site to come up with error

> Page isn't Redirecting Properly

Here is my .htaccess (minus the 301 redirects):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# force https
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# ensure https
# RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

As you can see I've tried a few different ways of achieving this, but **all** of them product the above error (they're not all uncommented at the same time).

My site is all https, except for this old links Google has when you search for them, but the redirects don't include the https part, and if I try to do a full url (e.g. `Redirect 301 /old/url/ https://www.example.com/old/url`) then it still doesn't work.

How do I enforce https for www.example urls without breaking the site?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to visit Settings » General page. From here you need to update your WordPress and site URL address fields by replacing http with https.

[image]

you need to set up WordPress redirects from HTTP to HTTPS by adding the following code to your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

If you want to force SSL and HTTPS on your WordPress admin area or login pages, then you need to configure SSL in the wp-config.php file. Add the following code above the “That’s all, stop editing!” line in your wp-config.php file:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Comment: This is already in place -> sorry :/ - and isn't `force_ssl_admin` for the admin pane;?